# find() after replaceWith() doesn't work (using BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, find, beautifulsoup

Please consider the following python session:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup("<p>This <i>is</i> a <i>test</i>.</p>"); myi = s.find("i")
>>> myi.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup("was"))
>>> s.find("i")
>>> s = BeautifulSoup("<p>This <i>is</i> a <i>test</i>.</p>"); myi = s.find("i")
>>> myi.replaceWith("was")
>>> s.find("i")
<i>test</i>
```

Please note the missing output of s.find("i") after line 4!

What's the reason for this? Is there a workaround?

EDIT: Actually, the example doesn't demonstrate the usecase, which is:

```
myi.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup("wa<b>s</b>"))
```

Whenever the inserted part contains itself nontrivial html code, I don't see how you could replace this syntax with something else. Just having

```
myi.replaceWith("wa<b>s</b>")
```

will replace the html special chars by entities.

Comment: Why do you need to replace with `sometag.renderContents()` instead of just replacing with `someTag`?

Comment: Okay, let's be more concrete by adding a different example... (see above, I edited again)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler answer : after your call to `replaceWith`, regenerate and clean `s` by calling `s = BeautifulSoup(s.renderContents())`. Then you can `find` again.

Comment: Note that `renderContents` is now called `encode_contents`

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that a `BeautifulSoup` object is considered an entire document.  `find` iterates through the document asking each element for the next element after it.  But when it gets to your `BeautifulSoup("was")`, that object thinks it is the whole document, so it says there is nothing after it.  This aborts the search too early.

I don't think BeautifulSoup is designed to have BeautifulSoup objects inside other BeautifulSoup objects.  The workaround is don't do that.  Why do you feel you need to use the first form instead of the second one, which already works?  If you want to replace an element with some bit of HTML, use a `Tag` for your replacement, not a `BeautifulSoup` object.

Comment: I admit that my example doesn't make clear, why I need this strange construction, I added further explanation above.

Comment: However, your explanation is totally correct, thanks! It would be great having a workaround though. (So don't be mad with me because I don't mark your answer as a solution.)

Comment: @thomas: There is a bug report about a similar issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1105148).  A comment says it is resolved but it still seems broken to me and I can't understand the explanation there.  You might want to comment on that bug and show your example and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

I think, I found a workaround, which solves the issue for me. I repeat the whole code again as a Python script to give a complete example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
s = BeautifulSoup("<p>This <i>is</i> a <i>test</i>.</p>")
myi = s.find("i")
s2 = BeautifulSoup("wa<b>s</b>")
myi_id = myi.parent.contents.index(myi)
for c in reversed(s2.contents):
    myi.parent.insert(myi_id + 1, c)
myi.extract()
```

Please note, that this won't work without `reversed()`. If you skip it, you don't only change the order of the elements. If you really want the order to be changed, you will have to write the following:

```
for c in list(s2.contents):
    myi.parent.insert(myi_id + 1, c)
```

Can somebody please explain, why skipping `list()` will omit `<b>s</b>`? (Please answer in a comment, because this is not the main question here.)

Comment: The reason you need `list` is because of what it says [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Adding%20a%20Brand%20New%20Element): an element can occur in only one place in the document.  When you do the `insert`, it removes the first element from `s2.contents` in order to insert it elsewhere.  Thus you are modifying `s2` while you iterate over it.