# Insert html string into BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to insert an html string into a BeautifulSoup object. If I insert it directly, bs4 sanitizes the html. If take the html string and create a soup from it, and insert that I have problems with using the `find` function. [This post thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455148/find-after-replacewith-doesnt-work-using-beautifulsoup) on SO suggests that inserting BeautifulSoup objects can cause problems. I am using the solution from that post and recreating the soup each time I do an insert.

But surely there's a better way to insert an html string into a soup.

**EDIT: I'll add some code as an example of what the problem is**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mainSoup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <div class='first'></div>
    <div class='second'></div>
</html>
""")

extraSoup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="first-content"></span>')

tag = mainSoup.find(class_='first')
tag.insert(1, extraSoup)

print mainSoup.find(class_='second')
# prints None
```

Comment: Can you show use your `html` and the expected result?

Comment: @user3100115 I've added some pretty straight forward code as an example if it helps.

Comment: hi did you find a solution without having to create a new tag?

Answer (score 18):

Simplest way, if you already have an html string, is to insert another BeautifulSoup object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''
<div>
 test1
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

soup.div.append(BeautifulSoup('<div>insert1</div>', 'html.parser'))

print soup.prettify()
```

Output:

```
<div>
 test1
<div>
 insert1
</div>
</div>
```

## Update 1

How about this? Idea is to use BeautifulSoup to generate the right AST node (span tag). Looks like this avoids the "None" problem.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mainSoup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <div class='first'></div>
    <div class='second'></div>
</html>
""", 'html.parser')

extraSoup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="first-content"></span>', 'html.parser')
tag = mainSoup.find(class_='first')
tag.insert(1, extraSoup.span)

print mainSoup.find(class_='second')
```

Output:

```
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Is explicitly declaring the parser what makes the difference?

Comment: Actually, we're not only declaring the parser, we're creating an entirely new parsed tree for the inserted html. BeautifulSoup(x) isn't a marker, it actually does a parse which results in a soup object.

Comment: Sorry if this is rude, did you read my post fully? I've mentioned that I already tried inserting a BeautifulSoup object and that it causes problems. Its why I was looking for a better method.

Comment: I had a problem with beautifulsoup4 version 4.4.1 - that soup tree broke when was modified with soup methods (any). Workaround was to use `html5lib` parser like ```tag.append( BeautifulSoup('<span class="first-content"></span>', 'html5lib') )```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is by creating a new tag `span` and insert it into your `mainSoup`. That is what the [**`.new_tag`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) method is for.

```
In [34]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [35]: mainSoup = BeautifulSoup("""
   ....: <html>
   ....:     <div class='first'></div>
   ....:     <div class='second'></div>
   ....: </html>
   ....: """)

In [36]: tag = mainSoup.new_tag('span')

In [37]: tag.attrs['class'] = 'first-content'

In [38]: mainSoup.insert(1, tag)

In [39]: print(mainSoup.find(class_='second'))
<div class="second"></div>
```