# is it possible to change parent of html element with python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Let's assume I have a html like following:

```
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
```

I want to move all `divs` with the class `answer-div` into the previous `question-div`. Can I handle it with beautifulsoup?

Comment: But shouldn't the question be more like, I tried this but it did not result that and now how do I fix this? rather than just *is it possible to ..*

Comment: @user5173426 yeah, just like u say brilliant man, I am not even trying it for last 2 hours.

Comment: Do you want to generate new HTML document? And if so WHY do you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hands-on experience with `beautifulsoup` but I will give this one a shot!

The way I look at it is, you find all the `div's` with `question` and `answer` separately.

```
div_ques_Blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_="question-div")
div_ans_Blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_="answer-div")
```

and then loop through the `question-div` to insert/append the `answer-div`

```
for divtag in div_ans_Blocks :
       print divtag.find_previous_sibling('div')
```

If the above `print` statement gives you all the `answer-div`, you can then try appending them instead of priting, [maybe like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229981/insert-html-string-into-beautifulsoup-object)

Comment: keep your shots that accurate. I just loop through questions and instead of finding the previous sibling, I just append the answer with that index. in the end, there must be an answer to every question, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [insert](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
<div class="question-div"></div>
<div class="answer-div"></div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for div in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"answer-div"}):
    div.find_previous_sibling('div').insert(0,div)
print(soup)
```

Output

```
<div class="question-div"><div class="answer-div"></div></div>

<div class="question-div"><div class="answer-div"></div></div>

<div class="question-div"><div class="answer-div"></div></div>
```