# Web-scraping problem, how to display data from 2 different sites in one html file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with display data from 2 different sites in the same html file (in one table).

I've been trying many things, searching for any solutions but nothing helps me. 
You can also link me any python/bs/web-scraping tutorial to my future "problems" :D

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

odpowiedz = requests.get(
    "https://www.nike.com/pl/w?q=react%20270&vst=react%20270")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(
    class_='product-card css-1pclthi ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-lg-4 va-sm-t product-grid__card')

title = [item.find(class_='product-card__title').get_text()
         for item in items]
price = [item.find(class_='product-card__price').get_text()
         for item in items]
linki = [item.find(class_='product-card__link-overlay').attrs['href']
         for item in items]

odpowiedz = requests.get(
    "https://www.nike.com/pl/w/air-max-97-buty-77f38zy7ok")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(
    class_='product-card css-1pclthi ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-lg-4 va-sm-t product-grid__card')

title = [item.find(class_='product-card__title').get_text()
         for item in items]
price = [item.find(class_='product-card__price').get_text()
         for item in items]
linki = [item.find(class_='product-card__link-overlay').attrs['href']
         for item in items]

wynik = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Model': title,
        'Cena': price,
        'Link': linki,
    })

print(wynik)
wynik.to_html('official.html')
```

Result of this program is id, product name, price and link(to  shoes in this example) from 1st website (nike react) and i want to add data from second site(nike air max 97) and add it also to table with my first result(nike react)

Comment: As I understood, you need to insert part of HTML code in an HTML file. To do it you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229981/insert-html-string-into-beautifulsoup-object

If that's what you need, mark your question as duplicate.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Result of this program is id, product name, price and link(to  shoes in this example) from 1st website (nike react) and i want to add data from second site(nike air max 97) and add it also to table with my first result(nike react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely a better way to do this. But here is a quick band-aid solution:-

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


title = []
price = []
linki = []

odpowiedz = requests.get(
    "https://www.nike.com/pl/w?q=react%20270&vst=react%20270")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(
    class_='product-card css-1pclthi ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-lg-4 va-sm-t product-grid__card')

title.append([item.find(class_='product-card__title').get_text()
         for item in items])
price.append([item.find(class_='product-card__price').get_text()
         for item in items])
linki.append([item.find(class_='product-card__link-overlay').attrs['href']
         for item in items])

odpowiedz = requests.get(
    "https://www.nike.com/pl/w/air-max-97-buty-77f38zy7ok")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(
    class_='product-card css-1pclthi ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-lg-4 va-sm-t product-grid__card')

title.append([item.find(class_='product-card__title').get_text()
         for item in items])
price.append([item.find(class_='product-card__price').get_text()
         for item in items])
linki.append([item.find(class_='product-card__link-overlay').attrs['href']
         for item in items])

flat_titles = [titles for sublisttitle in title for titles in sublisttitle]
flat_prices = [prices for sublistprice in price for prices in sublistprice]
flat_links = [links for sublistlinks in linki for links in sublistlinks]

wynik = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Model': flat_titles,
        'Cena': flat_prices,
        'Link': flat_links,
    })

print(wynik)
wynik.to_html('official.html')
```